# Erro no taxonomy.php

Tags: html, wordpress

Estou com o seguinte entrave:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare add_term_meta() (previously declared in
>   /home/xxx/public_html/wp-includes/taxonomy.php:1757) in
>   /home/xxx/public_html/wp-content/themes/theleader/framework/inc/taxonomy-metadata.php
>   on line 103

E não consigo encontrar uma solução, sugestões?

Answer (score 1):

A função `add_term_meta()` está sendo declarada duas vezes.

Uma no arquivo: `/home/xxx/public_html/wp-includes/taxonomy.php`

E outra no arquivo: `/home/xxx/public_html/wp-content/themes/theleader/framework/inc/taxonomy-metadata.php`

Uma função só pode ser declarada uma vez.

Sugestão: você pode criar um arquivo à parte para esta função, e nos dois arquivos anteriores pode realizar um `require_once 'pasta/arquivo_funcao.php';`

Comment: Sou meio leigo, não sei como realizar esse require.

Comment: Você cria um arquivo PHP, nele você coloca a função add_term_meta() e exclui ela dos outros arquivo, no lugar dela, nos outros arquivos, você escreve require_once 'nome_da_pasta/arquivo_com_a_funcao_add_term_meta.php';